# row num gives zero records

Tags: sql, oracle, count, oracle11g

I need to get the total no of records in a table for pagination purpose..it has some around 1 million records...the count is calculated as part of page load..i can do count query but it takes little more time thus increasing the time to page load.So to avoid that i have used

```
select ROW_NUMS,OWNER from ALL_TABLES where table_name='table1'
```

But the problem is that this query for some tables gives result as zero and also sometimes the  count is not correct(different from count query)

any idea how to update the all_tables data for a table and how all_table

Comment: Probably statistic is not up-to-date for that tables. You should gather it.

Comment: `row_nums` is *never* going to show an accurate count. It is always an estimate based on the data when the table was analyzed

Answer (score 1):

If You want the exact number of records in a table, You need to `select count(*)`. This result will be correct. `NUM_ROWS` has never been to provide the exact number of rows.

You can gather the table, but this will give you the estimate count.

```
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('<OWNER>', '<TABLE_NAME>');
```

Comment: ya..this seems to be working..as most of the table will be static in nature and row count will remain same only data will change

Answer (score 0):

To get an accurate row count you can get the database to do the heavy lifting before it sends the data to the client, e.g.:

```
SELECT t.*
      ,COUNT(*) OVER () AS row_count
FROM   my_table t;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to run ANALYZE statement to properly update that column

Comment: The use of analyze to gather statistics is a deprecated feature